# CppCMS tutorial: Linking template statically error: "fatal error: content.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, cppcms

From http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_tut_hello_templates

I'm following the tutorial and below is what I've done.

In `content.h`:

```
#include <cppcms/view.h>
#include <string>

namespace content  {
    struct message : public cppcms::base_content {
        std::string text;
    };
}
```

In `my_skin.tmpl`:

```
<% c++ #include "content.h" %>
<% skin my_skin %>
<% view message uses content::message %>
<% template render() %>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1><%= text %> World!</h1>
  </body>
<html>
<% end template %>
<% end view %>
<% end skin %>
```

Add include in `hello.cpp`:

```
#include <content.h>
```

Add controller in `hello.cpp`:

```
virtual void main(std::string /*url*/)
{
    content::message c;
    c.text=">>>Hello<<<";
    render("message",c);
}
```

When I link statically `my_skin.cpp` to `hello.cpp` by run `g++ hello.cpp my_skin.cpp -o hello -lcppcms -lbooster`, it give error below:

```
hello.cpp:1:21: fatal error: content.h: No such file or directory
```

I dont know why error since `hello.cpp` and `content.h` is in the same directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to include then using "content.h"

GCC include <> tag searches the file in the following path

> ```
> /usr/local/include
> libdir/gcc/target/version/include
> /usr/target/include
> /usr/include
> ```
>
> reference http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

If the file is in the same directory then you can add them using

> ## include "fileName.h"
>
> in which case the compiler will search in the current directory

However you can also add any path to the search path by using -L flag.
example

> gcc -L/path/to/library filename.cpp